# Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

Estou chamando um método para converter minha requisição ajax para uma data legível, mas fico recebendo a mensagem de que não foi definida a função, não entendo o porquê, já que é literalmente a função logo acima da que está a utilizando

```js
//converte o valor recebido em um objeto do tipo date em js
convertToJavaScriptDate: function (value) {
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    return dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
},


CarregaInfoComplementares: function (id, obj) {
    var Id = id;
    var tr = obj;
    $('.selectedRow').removeClass('selectedRow');
    $(obj).closest('tr').children().each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
    });
    dados_entrada = "{'Id':'" + Id + "'}"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Pacote.aspx/CarregaInfoComplementares",
        data: dados_entrada,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data, msg) {
            var row = $.parseJSON(data.d).dt[0];
            var datInicioValidade = convertToJavaScriptDate(row['DAT_INICIO_VALIDADE']);
            //mais codigo
       },
    });
},
```

Recebo o seguinte erro no console do navegador:
Uncaught ReferenceError: convertToJavaScriptDate is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só pra entender melhor, esse código todo está dentro de um objeto? Se ele estiver dentro de um objeto o correto para chamar sua função seria assim:

```js
objectName.convertToJavaScriptDate()
```

Esse `ReferenceError` provavelmente deve estar acontecendo por que sua função existe apenas dentro desse objeto onde ela foi declarada.

Comment: Valeu! Não sabia que precisava dizer o nome do objeto sendo que já estava dentro do próprio...